# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quantmod.theming'

Tags: python-3.x, quantmod

Trying to install quantmod in Python 3.6 and getting this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quantmod.theming'

Here are the imports:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
from plotly import tools
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser
import quantmod as qm
```

Here is the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e0fff5c4d1f1> in <module>()
      8 from datetime import datetime
      9 from dateutil import parser
---> 10 import quantmod as qm

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quantmod-0.1.3-py3.6.egg\quantmod\__init__.py in <module>()
     21 from __future__ import absolute_import
     22 
---> 23 from .core import *
     24 from .chart import *
     25 from .tools import (go_offline, go_online, is_offline,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quantmod-0.1.3-py3.6.egg\quantmod\core.py in <module>()
     11 import pandas_datareader.data as web
     12 
---> 13 from .chart import Chart
     14 
     15 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quantmod-0.1.3-py3.6.egg\quantmod\chart.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 from . import tools
---> 22 from . import factory
     23 from .valid import VALID_FIGURE_KWARGS, VALID_TRACES, OHLC_TRACES
     24 from .ta import *  # noqa : F405

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quantmod-0.1.3-py3.6.egg\quantmod\factory.py in <module>()
     12 from . import utils
     13 from . import tools
---> 14 from .theming.skeleton import SKELETON
     15 from .theming.themes import THEMES
     16 from .vendors.sources import SOURCES

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quantmod.theming'
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: https://github.com/jackluo/py-quantmod/issues/4

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I ran it in Spyder and it runs fine. Hmm, so it's a Jupyter thing. If anyone knows how to get it happening in Jupyter, that would be greatly appreciated.